# Why can't we ask questions that are just discussed?

Tags: discussion

I don't see anything wrong with it so why can't we ask questions that are just discussed?

Answer (score 6):

Because that's not what Arqade is about.  We're not a forum.  We specialize in specific, focused questions and answers.

Answer (score 6):

The entire StackExchange network (of which Arqade is part of) is about questions and answers - Q+A. One person asks a single, focused question, someone else answers with a specific (and hopefully correct) answer. In general, a question that is a good fit for Arqade will have about one or two possible correct answers.

Discussion questions aren't like that - there is no "right" answer in a discussion. That takes away the "A" part of Q+A, and therefore makes the question tough to score objectively. This is why we limit our question scope to narrowly focused areas.

This is obviously not the case in all scenarios... there is such a thing as a ["Good Subjective"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) questions, and also questions with many possible correct answers (such as strategy questions). But it's a good rule of thumb.